# Is there a way to replicate same animation for ios using @react-navigation/native-stack for a Stack Screen animation to slide_from_left?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm trying to replicate the behavior of animation to slide_from_left for android I need the stack screen to be show sliding from left to the right of the screen, the prop options accept `options={{animation: 'slide_from_left'}}` but the documentation says only android works for iOS it does the default animation from right to left, is there a work around or any other way to create this animation?

Link for the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#options

is there a work around or any other way to create this animation for iOS?